# Excel VB count the number of weeks between two cells

Tags: vba, excel

Hello everybody peeps,

I'm extremely new to VB and I've been taking bits of code of the web trying to create something quite simple. I'm trying to get excel to calculate the number of weeks between two cells with date values. The first cell is in a fixed location, the second cell is the last cell within that columns used range.

`Last` is a function I pinched off the web. I can't get this to work at all, any help would be much appreciated.

```
   Sub test_date_calc()



   Dim LastCell As String
   Dim nwks As Integer
   Dim rng As Range

   Set rng = Sheets("data13").UsedRange
   LastCell = Last(3, rng)
   nwks = (Cells(3, 2) - LastCell.Value) / 7
   If nwks > 13 Then

   MsgBox "greater"
   Else

   MsgBox "Less"

   End If
   End Sub
```

the `Last` function below, which may help

```
Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: When you say, not working..  Do you get errors, or does it give the wrong results? It's difficult to help if you don't give more information.

Comment: I get "invalid Qualifier" with LastCell highlighted. The code for the function "Last" may also be helpful

Comment: the code dosn't fit in here - sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your error is due to this line:

```
 nwks = (Cells(3, 2) - LastCell.Value) / 7
```

LastCell is a string so it doesn't need the `.Value`

```
 nwks = (Cells(3, 2) - LastCell) / 7
```

---

You can use the `DATEDIFF` function in VBA.

```
  DateDiff( interval, date1, date2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear] )
```

Usage example:

```
nwks = DateDiff("ww", Cells(3, 2).Value, LastCell.Value)
```

You can see the documentation for `DATEDIFF` [HERE](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php)

Comment: Thanks for this but I really wanted to see why the code I have at the top isn't working.

Comment: @VBA_noob240 I think I found what was causing the problem. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That works in as much as it gives a new error message "type mismatch" on "nwks = (Cells(3, 2).Value - Lastcell) / 7" not sure what that means. Thanks for you help by the way.

Comment: @VBA_noob240 that is because `LastCell` is equal to an empty string, so the code is trying to perform arithmetic on text. It needs `Cells(3, 2)` and `LastCell` to both be numeric for it to work.

Comment: Your right thanks, also 'Cells(3, 2)' returns the cell value while 'lastcell' returns the cell ref and not the value of that cell. Any ideas on how I could return the value.

Comment: change `rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)` to `rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Value` and `Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)` to `Last = rng.Range("A1").Value`